# How to put PHP associative array into Javascript "associative" array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an associative Array in PHP and I want to transfer it into an Javascript on the fly, how can I do that?

My PHP array looks something like this:

```
        $pairs = ["LBo"=>"Large Blocks", 
                  "Bo"=>"Blocks", 
                  "bo"=>" blocky"]
```

I get the PHP array size into JS using

```
  const pairsSize= "<?php print(count($pairs)); ?>"
```

Next I create a loop in which the indexname of the associative array and the assigned value has to be read from the PHP array. I'm stuck and I don't know how to do it.

```
    let lithPairs = []; //my JS "associative" array
    for (x = 0; pairsSize> x; x++) {
              ....
    }
```

I want the result to look like this;

```
 lithPairs['LBo']="Large Blocks";
 lithPairs['Bo']="Blocks";
 lithPairs['bo']="blocky";
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `let lithPairs = []` is ***not*** an associative array. It's a plain array and you attach random object properties to it. The equivalent of an associative array in JS is an object: `{}`

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need any loops or any other code to convert an associative array to JS. Encoding as JSON should be enough.

Comment: thanks i forgot about json

Answer (score 0):

use json encode php array and fetch it using URL or Cookies/ localstorage